# Can I download apk file from Google Play programmatically

Tags: android, google-developers-console, android-developer-api

I am trying to find a solution to download and install programmatically apk files of applications from Google Play Store to android device, but I can not find any description of api.

On many web resources where apk files are located (for example, https://apkcombo.com), the download link starts with "https://play.googleapis.com/download/by-token/download?token".

Is it possible for yourself to receive such a download link for any apk, how do these web resources get such links

Comment: They emulate a smartphone downloading from the google play store app. The base link is the one you mentioned, and the token is generated every time a download starts, which indicates the package name to be downloaded and which device is requesting it.